# Prove or disprove convergence in distribution of a poisson variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let

$$S \overset{d}{\sim} Poisson(\lambda).$$ I would like to determine 
$\frac{S-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ converges in distribution as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty.$ So my set up is:

$$\Pr\left[a \le \frac{S-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \le b\right] = Pr[S \le \sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda] - Pr[S \le \sqrt{\lambda} a + \lambda].$$

Where $$Pr[S \le \sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda] = \sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda} \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}.$$

But as $\lambda$ tends to infinity, it seems like I could simply examine the last term in the summation:

$$\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{\sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda}}{(\sqrt{\lambda}b + \lambda)!} \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{\sqrt{\lambda}b}\lambda^{\lambda}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\sqrt{\lambda} b+ \lambda)^{1/2}(\sqrt{\lambda} b+ \lambda)^{\sqrt{\lambda}b}(\sqrt{\lambda} b+ \lambda)^{\lambda}e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}b}e^{-\lambda}}$$

By Stirling's formula. And we see the $e^{-\lambda}$ cancel. However, I am not sure what to make of this, it certainly looks nothing like the normal distribution since the only exponential term is $e^{\sqrt{\lambda}b}$, which does not converge at large value of the exponent as it would in a normal.

1. First I would like to confirm if the steps thus far are correct. Especially the argument that it suffice to consider the largest term in the summation.
2. Secondly I would like to know if there's another way to attack this problem altogether.

Comment: So I know I definitely can't say $$\Pr\left[a \le \frac{S-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \le b\right] \rightarrow^n \Phi(b) - \Phi(a)$$ if that's what you had in mind?

Comment: You haven't assumed that $\lambda$ only takes integer values, and that b is also an integer, thus, its not clear that it can serve as an upper index of summation. Also, I'm not sure you can simply take the last term; however, you have not simplified your result at all, so it looks worse than it is. Try posting the simplified version.

Comment: Ah yeah my primary concern before diving into the algebra is that I am even on the right track. The answer below suggests a whole new way to tackle it (which I asked for). Be that as it may, is  there something I can do with that series to simplify it?

Comment: It simplifies to: $\frac{\lambda^{\sqrt{\lambda}b+\lambda}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\sqrt{\lambda} b+ \lambda)^{1/2+\sqrt{\lambda}b+\lambda}} \to 0$ for $b>0$

Comment: Do you mean the ugly result I wrote or the original summation? Either way if the summation $\rightarrow 0$ then $Pr[S \le \sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda]$ does not go to $\Phi(\sqrt{\lambda} b + \lambda)$, so to me it seems to contradict the solution below.. unless of course I'm missing something..

Comment: It was for your result for the last term. The last term goes to 0 as you increase $\lambda$. This contradicts nothing, since you have not established that the summation uniformly converges in $\lambda$

Comment: Either way, your approach does not look promising. The standard way to show convergence in distribution is via the characteristic or moment generating function or appeal to some version of the CLT.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more convenient way is to use moment generating functions.

MGF of Poisson$:= E[e^S]=e^{\lambda (e^t-1)}$.

Define a sequence of random variables $S_n$, where $S_n\sim Poi(n)$, then $S_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}X_j\;\;X_j\sim Poi(1)$

Also, $S_i-i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}(X_j-1)$

We can now use a convenient property of moment generating functions $\psi(t):Y_N=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_iX\implies \psi_{Y_N}(t)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^N\psi_i(a_it)$, provided that the $X_i$ are independent (not necessarily identically distributed).

For our particular case, we will need a second MGF to represent the "degenerate" distribution $\delta_a(x):MGF[\delta_a(x)]=e^{ta}$.

Now, we can see that $\frac{S_i-i}{\sqrt{i}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i \frac{X_j}{\sqrt{i}} - \frac{\delta_{1,j}}{\sqrt{i}} \implies MGF\left[\frac{S_i-i}{\sqrt{i}}\right]=e^{i\left(e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{i}}}-1\right)}\times e^{-t\sqrt{i}}=\exp\left[i\left(e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{i}}}-1\right)-t\sqrt{i}\right]$

Now, $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty} \exp\left[i\left(e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{i}}}-1\right)-t\sqrt{i}\right] = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$, which is the [MGF of a standard normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples). $\square$