# Determine the expected value of a geometric distribution given some generic underlying distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

This is a variation of the standard waiting time problem. Suppose you have a sequence of variables

$$X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots \overset{iid}{\sim} F(x)$$

where $F(x)$ is continuous.

And random variable $N$ where $N$ is the first value $n$ for which $X_n > X_0$. I would like to find $\Pr[N=n]$ and $E[N]$. So I did

$$\Pr[N=n] = \Pr[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \le X_0] = \Pr[X_1 \le X_0] \cdots \Pr[X_{n-1} \le X_0] = F(X_0)^{n-1}.$$

And the expectation is: 
$$E[N] = \sum_{n \ge 1} n F(X_0)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(F(X_0)-1)^2}.$$

But the expected value I computed does not need to be an integer. So I feel like something went wrong, what gives?

Comment: The expected value of an integer-valued random variable need not be an integer. (For example, if $X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$, then $\mathbb{E}[X]=p$.)

Comment: Oh right! So the logic I described looks correct to you?

Comment: One thing to note is that the probability and expected value should be real numbers, but the expressions you found are random variables (they contain $X_0$), so something is definitely wrong. Also, you forgot to include $X_n > X_0$ in your probability calculation.

Comment: Yes! That bugged me but I operated under the assumption that $X_0$ is fixed, which makes no sense especially since I capitalized $X_0$. So I am missing something conceptually here ...

Comment: Also shameless plug, please consider this question as well :)      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071390/prove-or-disprove-convergence-in-distribution-of-a-poisson-variable

Comment: OK, _now_ I have _fully_ solved the problem.  It turns out that the distribution of $N$ does not depend on which function $F$ is, as long as $F$ is a continuous c.d.f. We get $\Pr(N=n)=1/(n(n+1))$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Small hiccup. The expected value of N is $E[N] = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{n}{n(n+1)}$ and the sum diverges? I suppose it's possible that a random variable does not have a finite expectation ...

Comment: @chibro2 : Indeed, the expectation is infinite.

Comment: It's finally occured to me the next day that there is a simple way to show that $\Pr(N>n) = \dfrac 1 {n-1} - \dfrac 1 n$ without enumerating any permutations. I have now added that as another postscript in my posted answer. See below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, quoted from the question, is wrong:
$$
\Pr[N=n] = \Pr[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \le X_0] = \Pr[X_1 \le X_0] \cdots \Pr[X_{n-1} \le X_0] = F(X_0)^{n-1}.
$$
This would be correct if it said
$$
\Pr[N=n\mid X_0] = \Pr[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \le X_0\mid X_0] = \Pr[X_1 \le X_0\mid X_0] \cdots \Pr[X_{n-1} \le X_0\mid X_0] = G(X_0)^{n-1}
$$
where $G$ is the conditional c.d.f. given $X_0$.

If you want $\Pr(N=n)$ and you've got $\Pr(N=n\mid X_0)$, then that is some function of $X_0$, and is thus a random variable.  The **expected value** of that random variable is $\Pr(N=n)$.

The answer posted by karakusc says correctly that $\Pr(X_n>X_0)=1/2$, but then goes on to say that $\Pr(X_1>X_0\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n>X_0)= (1/2)^n$.  This mistakenly assumes the events $X_k>X_0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ are independent.  They are not independent since they all depend on $X_0$.  It would be correct to say that $\Pr(X_1>X_0\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n>X_0\mid X_0)= \left( \Pr(X_1\mid X_0) \right)^n$, since the events involved are conditionally independent given the value of $X_0$.  But the value of $\Pr(X_k>X_0\mid X_0)$ depends on $X_0$ in a way that itself depends on what the distribution of $X_0$ is.

**PS:** I have now begun to think that I missed an opportunity to progress further on this than I did in the answer above.  Stand by$\text{ }\ldots$

**PPS:** $\ldots$ and now I wonder why no one else pointed that out.

Very well, then, $X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. and their c.d.f. $F$ is continuous.

We have $N=n$ precisely if $X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \le X_0 < X_n$.  That is the probability that a uniformly distributed random permutation of $0,1,\ldots,n$ puts $0$ and $n$ in the last two positions, in that order. And that is
$$
\frac{\text{number of permutations of $1,\ldots,n-1$}}{\text{number of permutations of $0,1,\ldots,n$}} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac 1 {n(n+1)}.
$$

**PPPS:** $\ldots$ and now it has occured to me that there is a yet simpler way to characterize the distribution of $N$.  The probability that $X_0$ is the largest among $X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is $1/(n+1)$, since all of these random variables are equally likely to be the biggest.  Therefore $\Pr(N>n)=\dfrac 1 {n+1}$.  And so
$$
\Pr(N=n) + \Pr(N>n) = \Pr(N>n-1) = \frac 1 n,
$$
hence
$$
\Pr(N=n) + \frac 1 {n-1} = \frac 1 n
$$
and finally
$$
\Pr(N=n) = \frac 1 {n-1} - \frac 1 n.
$$

Comment: Is there a way to compute these things even though we are not guaranteed the existence of a pdf?

Comment: How you compute them would depend on what the c.d.f. $F$ is. You can say $\displaystyle\operatorname{E}(X_1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dF(x)$ regardless of whether there is a p.d.f., but how you compute that depends on which function $F$ is. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok thanks! The way OP posed the question seemed to imply that there would be expressions in terms of $F$ for general continuous cdfs $F$ [without using the Stieltjes integral], but it seems this is not the case.

Comment: Why is $\Pr(X_n > X_0) = 1/2$? I was not able to understand karakusc's answer, especially the "symmetry" part :\

Comment: @chibro2 : Say you have two random variables $A$ and $B$, and they both have the same continuous distribution (and "continuous" imples $\Pr(A=B)=0$) and they're independent.  Then $\Pr(A>B)=\Pr(B>A)$ because the distribution of the pair $(A,B)$ is the same as the distribution of the pair $(B,A)$.  That is symmetry. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Wow that pps answer, it's very similar to the the probability of three chords on a circle intersecting each other!

Answer (score 0):

Since $F(x)$ is continuous, $P(X_n=X_m)=0$ for all $m,n$, since otherwise $F(x)$ would need to have a point mass, which means it cannot be continuous. Then since $\{X_n \}$ is i.i.d., $P(X_n>X_0)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$, by symmetry.

Therefore $N$ is simply a geometric random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$, and $\mathbb{E}[N]=2$.

**Note:** This result is wrong since the events $\{ X_n>X_0\}$ are not independent, but I would like to keep it since it contains a correct side observation in the first paragraph. See Michael Hardy's post for the correct answer.

Comment: I find this erroneous.  I'll post an answer.

Comment: yeah the answer really scared me for a second!

Comment: OK you may be right. Should I delete it?

Comment: Right, the events $\{ X_n>X_0\}$ are not independent, so $N$ is not geometric.

Comment: Same comment duplicated from above: why is $\Pr(X_n > X_0) = \frac{1}{2}$? Is it because $E[X_0]$ is the mean? So half of the values of $X_n$ lies on one side of the mean?

Comment: Since $X_n$ and $X_0$ are i.i.d., $P(X_n>X_0)=P(X_0>X_n)$ due to symmetry. If $X_n$ and $X_0$ have zero probability of being equal, then these probabilities must sum to 1...

Comment: OK, _now_ I have _fully_ solved the problem.  It turns out that the distribution of $N$ does not depend on which function $F$ is, as long as $F$ is a continuous c.d.f. We get $\Pr(N=n)=1/(n(n+1))$. ${}\qquad{}$