# Central limit theorem in the setting of Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers, central-limit-theorem

**Setting**

Given $S_{\lambda} \overset{d}{\sim} \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Let $G_{\lambda}(t)$ be the distribution function of $\frac{S_{\lambda}}{\lambda}$. I need to determine $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow \infty} G_{\lambda}(t)$ when

1. $t>1$
2. $t<1$
3. $t = 1$

**Solution**

Taking hint from the way the question is asked, I let $\lambda = n$, so that

$$S_{n} = S_{\lambda} = X_1 + \ldots X_n$$

Where $X_j \overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} \operatorname{Poisson}(1)$ for all $j$. So I can see I'm in a CLT setting. However, I am not sure where to proceed from here. Ideas?

**Edit**
I presume $\frac{S_{\lambda}}{\lambda} \rightarrow 1$, but what kind of convergence is this? Furthermore, I assume $G_{\lambda}(t) \rightarrow^d \Phi(t)$ where $\Phi(t)$ is the normal distribution centered at $1$, but does the variance change as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071390/prove-or-disprove-convergence-in-distribution-of-a-poisson-variable/1071444#1071444 ?

Comment: It's conceptually similar but the t is really confusing me

Comment: Also I made more comments to further elaborate on my point of confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLT does hold here:

$\frac{S_n-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\to \mathcal{N}(0,1) \implies S_n\dot{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\lambda,\lambda)\implies \frac{S_n}{\lambda} \dot{\sim} \mathcal{N}(1,\lambda^{-1})\implies \frac{S_n}{\lambda}\xrightarrow{p} 1$

So, your ratio converges to $1$ in probability; but we can prove more:

Using your construction: $Var(S_n)=n \implies \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{Var(X_i)}{n^2}=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty \implies \frac{S_n-n}{n}\to 0\;a.s.\implies\frac{S_n}{n} \to 1\; a.s.$

So the ratio converges *almost surely*.

However, we only need convergence in probability to answer your questions:

$G_{\lambda}(t) \xrightarrow {d}  \mathcal{N}(1,\lambda^{-1}) \to \mathbf{1}_{\geq1}(t)$

Thus: $t<1 \implies  G_{\lambda}(t) \to 0,\;t=1 \implies G_{\lambda}(t) \to 0.5,\;t>1G_{\lambda}(t) \to 1$

Comment: why is it true that $S_n/\lambda \dot{\sim} \mathcal{N}(1,\lambda^{-1})$? Since, despite my presumption, wouldn't $S_n$ be centered at $\lambda$? Futhermore how do you know the variance is $\lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: Furthermore, could you explain this statement? $\mathcal{N}(1,\lambda^{-1}) \to \mathbf{1}_{\geq1}(t)$ why does it converge to some indicator function?

Comment: @chibro2 if $S_n$ is centered at $\lambda$ then $\frac{S_n}{n}$ is centered at $1$, also, when you divide by a constant, you reduce the variance by the *square* of that constant. That is just a basic property of variances under linear transformations.

Comment: By reduce the variance I assume you mean division? Thus $\lambda/\lambda^2 = \lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: @chibro2 yes, scaled down. I was a bit ambiguous with my comment.

Comment: And what does this statement $\mathcal{N}(1,\lambda^{-1}) \to \mathbf{1}_{\geq1}(t)$ mean? does it mean the normal converge to an indicator function? If so doesnt that mean the sum does not converge to a stable distribution, therefore no convergence in distribution?

Comment: @chibro2 no, it means that the CDF will converge to a step function, since the density will converge to a Dirac delta function centered at 1.

Comment: @chibro2 the tricky answer is at $t=1$ since it is at the discontinuity in the asymptotic CDF. However, since $t=1$ is the median of the sequence of CDFs, it is a constant and hence the limit is 0.5

Comment: @chibro2 btw: $X_n \xrightarrow{p} c \implies X_n \xrightarrow{d} c$